# EnumerateGenerator and Tuple

Tags: swift, enumerate

enumerate function returns type EnumerateGenerator.  But in Swift you are allowed to use that and assign to tuple.  How does EnumerateGenerator become a tuple?

```
Definition: func enumerate<Seq : SequenceType>(seq: Seq) -> EnumerateGenerator<Seq.Generator>

for (index, value) in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
       // How does EnumerateGenerator become a tuple?
}
```

In definition of EnumerateGenerator, Element is typealiased to a tuple, am I correct to assume that calling enumerate() is the same as calling EnumerateGenerator->next?

```
struct EnumerateGenerator<Base : GeneratorType> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {
    typealias Element = (index: Int, element: Base.Element)
    mutating func next() -> Element?
    typealias Generator = EnumerateGenerator<Base>
    func generate() -> EnumerateGenerator<Base>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ["For-In Statement"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) in the Swift documentation:

> A for-in statement allows a block of code to be executed once for each
>   item in a collection (or any type) that conforms to the SequenceType
>   protocol.
>
> The generate method is called on the collection expression to obtain a
>   value of a generator type—that is, a type that conforms to the
>   GeneratorType protocol. The program begins executing a loop by calling
>   the next method on the stream. If the value returned is not None, it
>   is assigned to the item pattern, the program executes the statements,
>   and then continues execution at the beginning of the loop. Otherwise,
>   the program does not perform assignment or execute the statements, and
>   it is finished executing the for-in statement.

So

```
for (index, value) in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
    // ...
}
```

is identical to

```
let enumGenerator = enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
var genFunc = enumGenerator.generate()
while let (index, value) = genFunc.next() {
    // ...
}
```

- `let enumGenerator = enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` returns a
  `EnumerateGenerator<Seq.Generator>` (in this
  case a `EnumerateGenerator<IndexingGenerator<Array<Int>>>`). This conforms to the 
  `SequenceType` protocol.
- `var genFunc = enumGenerator.generate()` returns again a
  `EnumerateGenerator<Seq.Generator>` (probably a copy of the `enumGenerator`).
  This conforms to the `GeneratorType` protocol.
- `genFunc.next()` returns `Element?` where `Element` is a type alias for
  `(index: Int, element: Base.Element)`.

  In this case, `next()` returns `(index: Int, element: Int)?`. This next function
  returns optional tuples until the array is exhausted, where it returns `nil`.